# Set Figure Size in Seaborn in PyPlot Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a piece of code to plot multiple scatter plots in one image -

```
columns_for_clusters = set(column_types_and_names['object']) - set(ignore_columns_in_model)
columns_for_clusters = list(columns_for_clusters)
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(math.ceil((len(column_types_and_names["int64"]) - 2)/3),3)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))

x = 0
for index in range(0,len(column_types_and_names["int64"])):
  if(column_types_and_names["int64"][index] != 'SalePrice' and column_types_and_names["int64"][index] != 'Id'):
    #train.plot(kind="scatter", x="SalePrice", y=column_types_and_names["int64"][index], ax=ax1[int(x / 3)][x % 3],figsize = (30,40), s = 1)
    g =sns.scatterplot(x="SalePrice", y=column_types_and_names["int64"][index],
          hue=columns_for_clusters[0],
          data=train, ax = ax1[int(x / 3)][x % 3]);
    x = x + 1
plt.show()
```

The size of the plots are incredibly tiny. How do I fix this?

I have to plot 12*3 plots
The plot worked in Pandas Plot. Is there a way to show scatter plot with categorisation colouring in Pandas Scatter Plot?

Comment: Line 4: `figsize=(bigger, bigger)`?

Comment: @it's-yer-boy-chet - didn't work for multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
columns_for_clusters = set(column_types_and_names['object']) - set(ignore_columns_in_model)
columns_for_clusters = list(columns_for_clusters)
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(math.ceil((len(column_types_and_names["int64"]) - 2)/3),3)
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 40))

x = 0
for index in range(0,len(column_types_and_names["int64"])):
  if(column_types_and_names["int64"][index] != 'SalePrice' and column_types_and_names["int64"][index] != 'Id'):
    #train.plot(kind="scatter", x="SalePrice", y=column_types_and_names["int64"][index], ax=ax1[int(x / 3)][x % 3],figsize = (30,40), s = 1)
    sns.scatterplot(x="SalePrice", y=column_types_and_names["int64"][index],
      hue=columns_for_clusters[0],
      data=train, ax = ax1[int(x / 3)][x % 3]);
    x = x + 1
plt.show()
```

Delete `g=`